# APNS: Is apns-push-type required for push messages when using Binary Provider API?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios13

I am currently sending push messages to my app using the Binary Provider API(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW1) which uses  streaming TCP socket.

Just recently Apple announced that there is a new Header flag 'apns-push-type' that need to be set for all push messages in order for iOS13 to recieve messages correctly (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns), otherwise the push message might be discarded. I have searched if this also is required when using the Legacy Binary Proviver without success.

Comment: It has come to my attention that Apple will depricate the Binary Provider API November this year (2020) so i guess the  correct solution here is to migrate to HTTP2 APNS api.